# STM32 USB CDC Will Not Return Data

Tags: c, usb, stm32, cdc

I am trying to use the STM32F303 Discovery Board to send back data via USB, but am running into some issues. Here is the code where the problem is happening:

```
void CDC_Receive_Callback(uint8_t *_buff, uint16_t _len) {
  uint8_t *sub_buff;            // Buffer to store sub strings (extracted data)
  uint8_t outputMsg[256] = "";  // Buffer for output message
  uint8_t command;              // Command
  uint8_t value;                // Command value

  // Extract the command
  sub_buff = (uint8_t *) strtok((char *) _buff, " ");
  command = (uint8_t) atoi((char *) sub_buff);

  // Extract the command value
  sub_buff = (uint8_t *) strtok(NULL, " ");
  value = (uint8_t) atoi((char *) sub_buff);

  // Check for extraneous data
  if (strtok(NULL, " ") != NULL) {
    command = 0;
  }

  // Perform command
  switch(command) {

    /* ...Command Options... */

    case CMD_LED_ON:
      //Acknowledge command
      CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t *) MSG_LED_ON, 
       strlen(MSG_LED_ON));

      //Turn on LED
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

      break;

    case CMD_RETURN_DATA:
      //Acknowledge command
      CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t *) MSG_RETURN_DATA, 
       strlen(MSG_RETURN_DATA));

      calculateData();

      //Build return message
      strcat((char *) outputMsg, "Calculation Results: \n");
      uint8_t value_as_string[100];

      sprintf((char *)value_as_string, "Data: %u\n", getData());
      strcat((char *) outputMsg, (char *)value_as_string);

      CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t *) outputMsg, 
      strlen((char *)outputMsg));

      break;
```

The CMD_LED_ON command completely works (the LED turns on and MSG_LED_ON is returned). The CMD_RETURN_DATA command, however, only sends MSG_RETURN_DATA over USB, but nothing else. I've tried simply sending MSG_RETURN_DATA twice:

```
case CMD_RETURN_DATA:
      //Acknowledge command
      CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t *) MSG_RETURN_DATA, 
       strlen(MSG_RETURN_DATA));

      CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t *) MSG_RETURN_DATA, 
       strlen(MSG_RETURN_DATA));

      break;
```

but MSG_RETURN_DATA is only displayed once. I thought the issue was calling CDC_Transmit_FS() twice, so I tried including MSG_RETURN_DATA in outputMsg to only call CDC_Transmit_FS() once:

```
case CMD_RETURN_DATA:
  calculateData();

  //Build return message
  strcat((char *) outputMsg, MSG_RETURN_DATA);
  strcat((char *) outputMsg, "Calculation Results: \n");
  uint8_t value_as_string[100];

  sprintf((char *)value_as_string, "Data: %u\n", getData());
  strcat((char *) outputMsg, (char *)value_as_string);

  CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t *) outputMsg, 
  strlen((char *)outputMsg));

  break;
```

and nothing is displayed in RealTerm. Here is my code for CDC_Transmit_FS():

```
uint8_t CDC_Transmit_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint16_t Len)
{
  uint8_t result = USBD_OK;
  USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef *hcdc = 
  (USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef*)hUsbDeviceFS.pClassData;

  if(hcdc->TxState != 0) {
    return USBD_BUSY;
  }

  USBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, Buf, Len);
  result = USBD_CDC_TransmitPacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);

  return result;
}
```

When I try to debug, it seems that when given the CMD_RETURN_DATA command,  CDC_Transmit_FS() always returns USBD_BUSY, at which point the code jumps to CDC_Receive_FS(), for reasons that I don't understand. Here is the code for CDC_Receive_FS():

```
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
  CDC_Receive_Callback(Buf, *Len);
  return (USBD_OK);
}
```

I'm at a loss as to how to get CMD_RETURN_DATA to successfully return the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** To expand on my question, after one transfer is made it seems that TxState never becomes 0. I modified CDC_Transmit_FS() to wait on TxState:

```
uint8_t CDC_Transmit_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint16_t Len)
{
  uint8_t result = USBD_OK;
  USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef *hcdc = (USBD_CDC_HandleTypeDef*)hUsbDeviceFS.pClassData;

  if(hcdc->TxState != 0) {
    return USBD_BUSY;
  }

  USBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, Buf, Len);
  result = USBD_CDC_TransmitPacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);

  //Wait for transmission to finish
  while(hcdc->TxState) ;

  return result;
}
```

and the program hangs inside the while loop. I've tried sending CMD_LED_ON, and the computer receives the message like it's supposed to, so I know the transmission has completed, but the program remains stuck inside the loop. My expectation is that the PCD_EP_ISR_Handler() should call HAL_PCD_DataInStageCallback(), which calls USBD_LL_DataInStage(), which calls pdev->pClass->DataIn(), which is another name for USBD_CDC_DataIn(). This USBD_CDC_DataIn() is what sets TxState back to 0. For some reason this function doesn't seem to be getting called.

Comment: when calling `strtok()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @Robert have you found any solution to the stuck TxState of the USB? I have run into this problem every once in awhile. It's almost like an interrupt is being missed...

Comment: No, I never did find a solution. I ended up using a workaround in my project that didn't require sending data over USB like this. I've speculated that the issue involves an interrupt with a higher priority interrupting my code, but I haven't delved much farther into the problem after this post.

Comment: Same problem here in 2022, may be TxState need the code to get out of the function to clear?

Comment: Confirmed, this can be solved by implementing 2, 3, 4 or more paralell buffers, then your send function just do memcopy to the next buffer. Finally in the main loop check if buffer1 needs to be sent and send it. The same with buffers 2, 3, 4. It seems that the TxState gets cleared if you just poll this way in the main loop. When you send just check if state is busy, if it is, then don't send and the next loop may be you can send the buffer.